# How to remove unwanted label on ElementUI pagination component?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am using ElementUI for a Vue project, and I want to remove the label on pagination, but there is no attribute for this.

What would be the best way to remove the label on "pagination select"?

Here's [the pagination](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/pagination)!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/USuBy.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label can not be easily removed because it's hard coded in the source code : https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/4f93968db41899c235ad9e388eaf2ac052805cd3/packages/pagination/src/pagination.js#L189

One easy hackish way of solving your problem would be to override the i18n.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Element from 'element-ui'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en'

locale.el.pagination.pagesize = ''

Vue.use(Element, { locale })
```

Comment: Don’t hesitate to accept this answer if it helped you ! :)